# Conexion JAVA NetBeans con Oracle 12C

Tags: java, oracle-11g, netbeans-8.2

Hola a todos esperando se encuentren bien.

Estoy usando JAVA NetBeans 8.2 y tengo credenciales para conectarme a una base de datos Oracle Enterprise 12c dicha base de datos ya le he conectado con Oracle Developer en mi PC local sin problemas.

Ahora quiero desarrollar una aplicación JAVA para realizar las consultas al servidor donde se aloja la base de datos, pero me arroja error en la conexión.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for .............

Estas son las lineas de conexiónn:

```
// Load the JDBC Driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

// Create a connection
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.net:puerto:Servicio", "Usuario", "Password");
```

EDITO: Cambie esta parte de la conexión:
"jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.net:puerto**/**Servicio", "Usuario", "Password");

Como me di cuenta, conecte NetBeans manualmente con los servicios que proporciona y viendo la conexion SQLDeveloper que ya tengo me di cuenta que no es un SID si no un Service Name.
Googlando, encontre tambien la diferencia entre SID y Service Name.

Descargue el driver: **ojdbc7.jar**

**Agrego una imagen del driver en la carpeta especificada hay que hacer algo adicional a eso?**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguna idea de cual podría ser el error?

DS

Comment: En donde estas colocando el driver

Comment: El driver debe ser especificado dentro de la variable CLASSPATH., ¿lo tienes registrado?

Comment: Verifica que el Jar del driver este en tu proyecto en la parte izquierda del IDE debe estar la carpeta Libraries o lib en la cual debe estar el controlador, si no esta puedes agregandola dando click derecho o si en tu proyecto usas un manejador de dependencias como Maven agrega la dependencia en el pom.xml

Comment: @EduardoMarin
Si lotengo cargado en el proyecto en la carpeta libraries.
Tengo que hacer algo adicional a eso?
Edite la pregunta para agregar una imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código parece ser correcto, pero de acuerdo al error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

En este caso es importante que tengas definida en tu variable de ambiente `CLASSPATH` la ruta donde se encuentra `ojdbc7.jar`.

Aunque para la versión 7 lo puedes realizar dentro de tu Manifest en `Class-Path`, ejemplo:

```
$ cat MANIFEST.MF
Main-Class: JdbcCheckup
Class-Path: /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar /oracle/client/o12r1/jlib/orai18n.jar
```

Revisa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275320/ojdbc7-jar-is-in-classpath-but-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-or

Comment: He editado la pregunta agregando la imagen donde tengo cargado el driver, algo mas que tenga que hacer adicional a esto?